# Changing jtextfield depending on other jtextfield JAVA

Tags: java, jtextfield

I am trying to set the text in side jtprecosiva_produtos.
When jtprecocompra_produtos or jttxlucro_produtos values are changed in jtextfield it will update the value in jtprecosiva_produtos. But for some reason I am having trouble with it, as it wont work and nothing shows I think i have done all the transformations from sting to int and int to string correct, so If anyone could help it would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
private void jtprecocompra_produtosInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:

     int precocompra_produtos=0;
     int txlucro_produtos=0;

     precocompra_produtos = Integer.parseInt(this.jtprecocompra_produtos.getText());
    txlucro_produtos = Integer.parseInt(this.jttxlucro_produtos.getText());

    int precosiva_produtos=0;

    precosiva_produtos = precocompra_produtos + (precocompra_produtos*(txlucro_produtos/100));


    jtprecosiva_produtos.setText(Integer.toString(precosiva_produtos));

}
```

Comment: Kindly verify that `jtprecocompra_produtosInputMethodTextChanged()` is being invoked on input

Comment: This is what I am getting https://gyazo.com/4067dc9508ca6e8b142a684b3d452218
It should update Preco S/Iva

Comment: i am not sure if it makes a difference, but i use String.valueOf(int) . also do you want to always update the tf if your input changes?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to update the textfield when ever input changes